# How to implement go live option in exoplayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am trying to implement a go live option when playing a video through exoplayer. To explain what I mean by 'Go Live' I'll give an example.

1. User plays a live video on the exoplayer.
2. User clicks pause on the player.
3. A 'Go Live' Button should appear letting user shift to latest point in the stream.

I see similar functionality on youtube and wanted to implement the same in my app. I see there are `getTotalBufferedDuration()` and similar methods related to buffer lenght and size. But having a thread running and looking at this value and displaying the 'Go Live' option looks like a bad implementation. So if anyone can suggest on a approach.

My current implementation is to provide a 'Go Live' text on the player for user to manually seek to latest player offset

```
TextView go_live = view.findViewById(R.id.go_live);
go_live.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    player.seekToDefaultPosition();
  });
```